# How can I know if a user has access to all or just some resources with Cancan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan, access-control

I have a Rails 3 application that uses Cancan for authorization. I have the following logic in my application: An admin has access to manage all other users, and has `can :manage, User` set in the ability file. A company owner has access to manage all users under his company, and has `can :manage, User, company_id: user.company_id` set in the ability file.

In my `UserController#index`, i need to call one method if the user has access to manage all the other users, and another method if the user only can access users from his company. Is there any way to do this with CanCan?

Comment: How do you have the admin role defined? If you already have a distinction between admins and company owners you could probably check for that in the controller as well.

Comment: They have different roles. And yes, I could do that, but I rather keep the role-checking to one place and use cancan all other places if it's possible.

Comment: I feel you, that's how I'd like it to work myself. :) My limited understanding of authorization still says this sounds more like checking _roles_ than _abilities_.

Answer (score 3):

As discussed in the question comments, this sounds like a case of *roles* vs *abilities*.

If there already is a role system in place, and the logic for choosing between methods maps directly to these roles, then going through CanCan abilities is unnecessarily complex. CanCan is good at checking for abilities on specific model objects, classes and collections but not at going back to the original logic behind why those abilities were awarded in the first place.

In this specific case, there would need to be a way to refer to the case `"can manage all Users in Company X but NOT all Users"`. It might be possible to accomplish with some if-else structure, but I don't think it is what you *actually* want. Especially if your ability logic changes over time it may not make sense anymore. One example is the corner case where all users belong to the same company, would it be desirable that the `"all Users"` method is called even for non-admin company owners?

My suggestion therefore is to check the roles directly, much like you already do in your `Abilities` class. But I feel your pain. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I know this an old question but I also ran into this situation. I was also looking to do all role checking in `ability.rb` file in one place.

What I ended up doing was far from ideal, but just noting it down if anyone wants to go that road. I defined a new ability like this in the `ability.rb`:

```
can :manage, :all_users if user.admin?
```

Please note that `:all_users` is just a random name that I chose and not some magic method in cancan.

After defining this ability, I was able to do like this in the controller:

```
if can? :manage, :all_users
  call_method_which_can_access_all_users
else
  call_method_which_can_access_only_some_users
end
```

But, it would have been great if Cancan gave us something like `can? :manage, User, :all` depending on whether there is a hash for filtering users after the `User` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using cancan with device, in my projet i used probably the same you want

```
if user_signed_in?
  if current_user.has_role? :admin
    @users = User.all
  end
else
  @users = User.where(current.user.company_id == company_id)
end
```

Comment: This does not address my problem. I wondered if there was any way to do this with cancan, to avoid having role checks in more than one place.

Answer (score 0):

In controller action you should do something like:

```
#load @user variable 
begin
  authorize! :manage, @user
  #code when access is granted
rescue CanCan::AccessDenied
  #code when access is denied
end
```

Comment: This does not address my problem. There is not a single user, but a collection of users.